# Organize 3 files: PHP, HTML, JS and Smarty

Tags: php, javascript, html, smarty

I have a php code page that pull data from a database. The data then should go into javascript, which is a separate .js file (and i need to use Jquery too). I want to separate my .js and my main html page too. How would you do it, which one should be included in which?
And if you also use Smarty, how will that change the structure?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I'm generating Javascript data on the server side, I try to keep it entirely separate from the rest of the Javascript and HTML code. The cleanest way to do this is often to implement a basic API for your data: Create a PHP page that serves up pure JSON data from the database based on the URL and/or querystring, then use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to load it from the server. This approach avoids the cruft of generating Javascript with PHP, and allows for asynchronous loading of data, which may improve your UI.

If you don't want to deal with an asynchronous load, you can generate a file with just enough Javascript to define a variable:

```
echo 'var data = ' . json_encode($data) . ';';
```

and then refer to `data` in your subsequent Javascript.

Because this keeps the data wholly separate from your HTML and other Javascript files, it shouldn't have any influence at all on how you set up your templates.

Comment: I have something similar. I do <?php echo json_encode($data);?> in my .js....And I use <script src..> after the ?> in my main php file to get the data...Is that the right way...and what about the html and smarty

Comment: @William - this shouldn't affect your HTML and Smarty templating at all - that's the main point. In the first option, the only change is that you need to run `$.getJSON` in your Javascript code to get the data; in the second option (which sounds like what you're doing), all you need is a <script> tag in your HTML to load the data as a Javascript file. Other than that, this is entirely decoupled from the HTML - that's the advantage of doing it this way.